# Prevent Page refresh in angularjs 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to prevent page refresh using browser / f5 button in angularjs 1.4 application. I have gone through other SO answers. I'm using the below code snippet. but, it doesn't work. Can someone tell what's wrong with it?

```
app.run(function($window){
    var windowElement = angular.element($window);
    windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
    // do whatever you want in here before the page unloads.        
    event.returnValue = "Refresh is disabled";
    // the following line of code will prevent reload or navigating away.
    event.preventDefault();
});
})
```

Where `app` is angular module

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, it should work. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the form of fiddle/plunk.

Comment: @estus I have put a plunker. Can you please check this one - https://plnkr.co/edit/bKS9vmExU7AglH3362u3?p=info

Comment: Yes, this works if the plunker runs in separate window. And it won't work if it is iframe.

Comment: it asks for "Confirm Form Resubmission". Are you saying about that?